# Geneos data extraction

Tags: monitoring, extract, geneos

We are planning to use geneos reporting service for extracting data from application DB. But the problem is the geneos active console should remain open for reporting extraction to take place ie somebody needs to monitor it 24/7. Is there any solution/ any other option for data extraction using geneos?  T

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Geneos, the purpose should be monitoring. You are not clear when you say 'planning to use geneos reporting service for extracting data'. What is the purpose of extracting data? Is it monitoring? If yes, you have two options for monitoring - one is active console and the other is dashboard. You do not have to monitor 24/7, there are several alerting options available. Please elaborate your requirements to suggest further.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching on the Database Logging section in the GSE?

Extracting historical data can be useful for post incident analysis - for example CPU Spikes or Memory usage issues.

Online info:
https://resources.itrsgroup.com/ActiveConsole2/user_guide/index.html?highlight=database%20logging#database-logging

But surely if you are looking at historical data of a database, couldn't you look directly on the database?